# Breakpoints are not working with Javascript and VSCode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

I am following this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4v_Fhq2E1Oo

My server is XAMPP

Launch.json is below

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "msedge",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Edge Against Localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost/test/index.html",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

index.html is below

```
<head>
    <title>Read Text File</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="myDynamicTable"></div>
    <script>

         window.onload = () => {
              document.write("TEST:");
         }
    </script>  
</body>
```

I opened the entire directory from c:\htdocs\test in VSCode

When I run Debug from the Debug menu, or use F5, I can see `TEST:` is printed on the webpage

However, when I set a breakpoint on the same line in VSCode, it never stops on the breakpoint. And the red breakpoints turn into a white hollow circles while debugging

I tried this on multiple computers, I'm running edge browser on windows 10

What is missing to get breakpoints to work?

I installed the recommended Microsoft Edge Tools for VS Code but it still does not work. Do I need to install node.js, or does this come installed already?

Comment: Did you try [`Debug: Open Link`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/browser-debugging#_open-link-command)

Comment: I feel liek these instructions skip over several steps, which are not even mentioned in the video. Why is URL 
      "url": "http://localhost:8000" I don't see Vs Code starting a localhost server, do I need some kind of a server extension?

Comment: Next, where can I add this line to launch edge exe correctly `edge.exe --remote-debugging-port=9222 --user-data-dir=remote-debug-profile` and where do I define this debugging port

Answer (score 0):

solved by installing  Node.js. Unfortunately these tutorials, especially microsoft official ones, don't provide this information